# How can I restrict the Sonar JavadocMethod rule to filenames including "Controller"?

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

I have a pre-existing Java project, that Sonar Analysis was recently applied to.  There are a large number of CheckStyle JavadocMethod rule violations.

How would I restrict the JavadocMethod rule, to apply only to java filenames with the pattern "*Controller*.java" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *[JavadocMethod](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod)* check does not offer an option to limit itself to certain files, so this cannot be done easily. But - you could:

- Write a [custom filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingfilters.html) which suppresses all *JavadocMethod* warnings that occur in files which do not match a pattern. This is not difficult - the example on the linked page covers just that case. But it requires you to deploy the filter and that may be a bit of a hassle.
  I am not sure if this works in Sonar. I use custom Checkstyle checks in Sonar all the time, but I haven't tried custom filters yet.
- Write a subclass of Checkstyle's `JavadocMethodCheck` which adds an option to apply itself only to certain files ([Sonar Examples](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/), [Checkstyle tutorial](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html)). This is a sure bet if custom filters cannot be added to Sonar.
- If you are using Eclipse, you can configure it to use different rule sets based on filename. You would do that using the "advanced" configuration setting in the project properties. Your regexes would be `Controller\.java$` to match all controllers, and `.{10}(?<!Controller)\.java$` to match the other Java files. This approach could also be applied to a stand-alone or Ant-based Checkstyle run, but not to Sonar.

I am sorry that there is nothing easier available to you - but that's how things are at the moment ...
 Good luck!

Comment: Your Sonar tutorial Link is outdated, if you can please update it.

Comment: Just did. The old tutorial is no longer there, but SonarQube works differently today anyway. Updated to a more useful collection of examples.